# MouseOver event has TypeError: Error #1009, any helps?

Tags: flash

I am creating some animation involve mouse over, mouse over out and mouse down event. Whenever I mouse down the Movie Clip and it goes to another frame, the common error 1009 will appear in the output box. The animation works but the error still appears, can I just ignore the error since the animation works? Or is there any way to solve my coding problem? Any help is much appreciated!!!

Below is the coding on the Movie Clip:

```
africaMiddleEast.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mover);
africaMiddleEast.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,moverout);
africaMiddleEast.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mdown);


function mover(e:MouseEvent):void{
    africaMiddleEast.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function moverout(e:MouseEvent):void{
    africaMiddleEast.gotoAndStop(1);
}

function mdown(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxO9h.png)

Comment: Because (probably) when you move to another frame, that **africaMiddleEast** thing is no longer on timeline on that frame, so when **MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT** hits (and it does because mouse is out of it, right?) your code tries to access a non-existing thing. You'll probably fix it if you unsubscribe all the events before you **gotoAndPlay(2);**

Comment: could u please guide me how to unsubscribe all the events? thanks for your kind help :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to unsubscribe all the events before you **gotoAndPlay(2);**

```
africaMiddleEast.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut);
africaMiddleEast.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver);
africaMiddleEast.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);

function onOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    africaMiddleEast.gotoAndStop(1);
}

function onOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    africaMiddleEast.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    africaMiddleEast.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut);
    africaMiddleEast.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver);
    africaMiddleEast.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);

    gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the event listeners are still there and the error still remains. I have tried another way and solved the problems already. I try to make the frames of africaMiddleEast longer to cover all the other elements so the actionscript can still find the mouse over out script along the animation. And it works! :D